# How to send email notification by day and time in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I send email notification automatically with the only trigger is the day and time?

For example:
    I want to send an email notification automatically every Friday at 12 midnight.

Comment: Use google-father of all answers.

Comment: you can use cron jobs: http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cronjob or crontabs

http://service.futurequest.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/23

The cron daemon is a long running process that executes commands at specific dates and times. To schedule one-time only tasks with cron, use at or batch. For commands that need to be executed repeatedly (e.g. hourly, daily or weekly), use crontab, which has the following options:

crontab filename    Install filename as your crontab file.

crontab -e  Edit your crontab file.
crontab -l  Show your crontab file.

crontab -r  Remove your crontab file.

MAILTO=user@domain.com  Emails the output to the specified address.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a database underneath, you could store the date of the last mail in the database. The script then checks, what the last date in your database is. If this is more than n days in the past it sends a new mail and overwrites the date in the database with the current date.

Alternatively you could simply use [Cron-jobs](http://support.modwest.com/content/5/125/en/can-i-run-a-php-script-on-cron.html).

Use **[cron](http://support.modwest.com/content/5/125/en/can-i-run-a-php-script-on-cron.html)**. Your `cronjob` file would look roughly like this:

```
* * */5 * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /www/scripts/myscript.php
```

That's pretty much it. Easy as pie!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, The best way is using a cron job...

Comment: this post has provided an answer. . . It gives a keyword on "how to" send a timed email. I just need the "keyword" and its up to me now how do I utilize that. Also, I've already upvoted a post so don't worry about it. Sorry no offense :)